# Show if $\mathfrak p$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$ then $\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p$ is the only prime ideal of $R_\mathfrak p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, localization

Show if $\mathfrak p$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$ then $\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p$ is the only prime ideal of $R_\mathfrak p$.

Here are what I know and don't need to prove: I know $\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p$ is the maximal ideal of $R_\mathfrak p$.
I know $R_\mathfrak p$ is a local ring and so $R_\mathfrak p$ is the unique maximal ideal.
And I know the set of maximal ideals is the set of non-units.
Also, I know for $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $R$, $\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p$ also is a prime ideal of $R_\mathfrak p$.
How can I connect these ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You can read about primes in rings after localisation in any textbook about commutative algebra. The assertion is tautological with that basic knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

The prime ideals in a ring of fractions $S^{-1}R$ correspond bijectively to the prime ideals $\mathfrak q$ of $R$ such that $\mathfrak q\cap S=\varnothing$. In the present case, this means $\mathfrak q \subset \mathfrak p$. By the minimality of $\mathfrak p$, this implies $\mathfrak q=\mathfrak p$.

Comment: thank you for answering, but isn't $q$ is a sub-ring of $R$, how come $q∩R=∅$?

Comment: No, a proper ideal isn't a subring: a subring (in commutative algebra) *must* contain $1$.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but the OP is right to question $\mathfrak{q} \cap R = \varnothing$ (which is nonsensical since $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq R$): it should be $\mathfrak{q} \cap S = \varnothing$.